# Replace a character in a url that uses &

Tags: php, function, character-encoding, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places API...Im trying to store a location that has a &(Ampersand). I cant seem to encode the the variable. For Example the business name is called Dave & Busters but I can use the & in the url for the request url because thats reserved for parameters. I tried replacing the & if found using these two functions. Maybe I using it wrong,..

```
$name = 'Dave & Busters';
if (strpos($name, '&') !== false) {
//& SIGN FOUND
 //WONT WORK FOR URL NEED TO REPLACE
$name = str_replace('&', 'and', $string);

}
$name = urlencode($name);
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=10&type=restaurant&keyword=$name&key=myKey";
```

EDIT* Just using the urlencode() I get this. The Dave+ only shows

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7455483,-73.5951152&radius=10&type=restaurant&keyword=Dave+&key=AIzaSyD4rcVpAgnP650-DCeL2L4zTnPSo4d81vk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `urlencode()` for any data used in a query string.

Better yet, just use `http_build_query()`:

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' . http_build_query([
  'location' => $lat . ',' . $long,
  'radius' => 10,
  'type' => 'restaurant',
  'keyword' => $name,
  'key' => 'myKey'
]);
```

Comment: I am using the urlencode but it keeps outputting up to Dave+ only

Comment: @Carlitos Stop replacing stuff before `urlencode()`.

Comment: I tried doing that as well. I dont get any response because the parameters are being confused with the dave & busters ampersand 

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=10&type=restaurant&keyword=$name&key=myKey";

Comment: thank you. It was my mistake. The jquery ajax wasnt passing Dave & Busters completely. It kept cutting off at Dave. I had to encode the variable with encodeURIComponent(). Then it finally worked smoothly.